# How to install googlevis package properly on RStudio?

Tags: r

## IDC4U_Unit 4_Data Visualization

> #
>
> ## Load Packages
>
> #
>
> install.packages("googleVis")
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/googleVis_0.6.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 940725 bytes (918 KB)
downloaded 918 KB

package ‘googleVis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\library’ for modifying
Try removing ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\library/00LOCK’

> library(googleVis)
>   Error in library(googleVis) : there is no package called ‘googleVis’
>
> #
>
> ## Load Canada Imports Data
>
> #
>
> Imports <- read.csv("C:/Users/jaysu/OneDrive - orchestrate cutting-edge web-readiness/VHSOntario12/IDC4U/cansimMotionChartImports.csv")
>   head(Imports)
>     Ref_Date    GEO  TRADE               BASIS                  SA           PTP  Value Difference PercentageDifference
>   1     1997 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 211258          0                  0.0
>   2     1998 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 233517      22259                 10.5
>   3     1999 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 249200      15683                  6.7
>   4     2000 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 266165      16965                  6.8
>   5     2001 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 253913     -12253                 -4.6
>   6     2002 Canada Import Balance of payments Seasonally adjusted United States 254856        944                  0.4
>   dim(Imports)
>   [1] 532   9
>   summary(Imports)
>       Ref_Date        GEO               TRADE              BASIS                SA                PTP                Value          Difference
>    Min.   :1997   Length:532         Length:532         Length:532         Length:532         Length:532         Min.   :     0   Min.   :-45298.0
>    1st Qu.:2001   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:  1314   1st Qu.:   -40.0
>    Median :2006   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :  2804   Median :   122.5
>    Mean   :2006                                                                                                  Mean   : 14819   Mean   :   520.0
>    3rd Qu.:2011                                                                                                  3rd Qu.:  5544   3rd Qu.:   503.0
>    Max.   :2015                                                                                                  Max.   :363036   Max.   : 37231.0
>    PercentageDifference
>    Min.   :-100.000
>    1st Qu.:  -2.625
>    Median :   4.700
>    Mean   :   7.995
>    3rd Qu.:  14.500
>    Max.   : 230.200
>
> MotionImports <- gvisMotionChart(Imports, 
>   +                           idvar="PTP", 
>   +                           timevar="Ref_Date")
>   Error in gvisMotionChart(Imports, idvar = "PTP", timevar = "Ref_Date") : 
>     could not find function "gvisMotionChart"
>   plot(MotionImports)

It keeps showing an error whenever I try to troubleshoot or do a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to try the following.

```
# Install Rtools and googleVis
install.packages(c("Rtools", "googleVis"))

# Load googleVis
library(googleVis)
```

You might also want to save your script in the same folder as your local data, and then change the working directory to that folder. You can do this in RStudio using:

*Session > Set Working Directory > To Source File Location*

After that, you can try importing the data as usual.